# Regexp_like not working properly in case statement (in Oracle PL/Sql)

Tags: plsql

My following case statement in Oracle gives only 'Others' in flag column for all records though the other conditions satisfy.

```
create table pca_title2 as
(select executive_id,title,
case
when    regexp_like (title,'^Sales$','i')   then    'Sales'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Ecommerce$','i')   then    'Ecommerce'
when    regexp_like (title,'^E-commerce$','i')  then    'E-commerce'
when    regexp_like (title,'^optimization$','i')    then    'optimization'
when    regexp_like (title,'^optimisation$','i')    then    'optimisation'
when    regexp_like (title,'^optimise$','i')    then    'optimise'
when    regexp_like (title,'^optimize$','i')    then    'optimize'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Online.Cust.experience$','i')  then    'Online.Cust.experience'
when    regexp_like (title,'^UX$','c')  then    'UX'
when    regexp_like (title,'^user Experience$','i') then    'user Experience'
when    regexp_like (title,'^operations$','i')  then    'operations'
when    regexp_like (title,'^GM$','c')  then    'GM'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Executive Director$','i')  then    'Executive Director'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Executive Chairman$','i')  then    'Executive Chairman'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Chief Officer$','i')   then    'Chief Officer'
when    regexp_like (title,'^General Manager$','i') then    'General Manager'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Chair$','i')   then    'Chair'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Advisor$','i') then    'Advisor'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Overseers$','i')   then    'Overseers'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Board Member $','i')   then    'Board Member '
when    regexp_like (title,'^Member of Board$','i') then    'Member of Board'
when    regexp_like (title,'^Chief Operating Officer$','i') then    'Chief Operating Officer'
when    regexp_like (title,'^COO$','c') then    'COO'
else 'others'
end as flag
from pca);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say the regex is working as it's specified.  However you did not provide any data.  Most likely your regex isn't written to catch what you want. It looks like you are looking for matches where the title is any one of those (mostly case- insensitive) strings.  So it will not matching anything that contains text before or after.

```
Chair - match
Chairs - no match
GM - match
GMC - no match
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely your regexp works correctly but not in the way you think it should work. You don't show us any data so we can't say for sure.

Because you use anchors `^$` all your regexps match only exact strings and because you have `i` option the match is case insensitive. This means that in your data you don't have string `SALES` but maybe `SALES X`.

Below you see two examples A and B. The example A is simplified version of your example. However it might not do what you want but hopefully it gives you and idea what you might be doing wrong. The example B shows to you how to match (case insensitively) any string that is having substring `sales`.

```
with
x(id, title) as (
  select 1, 'Sales' from dual union all
  select 2, 'Ecommerce' from dual union all
  select 3, 'Online.Cust.experience' from dual union all
  select 4, 'user Experience' from dual union all
  select 5, 'Sales with postfix' from dual union all
  select 6, 'Something else' from dual
)
select 'A' as example, id, title
,case 
   when lower(title) in ('sales', 'ecommerce', 'online.cust.experience') then title
   else q'[It's something else]'
 end as flag
from x
union all
select 'B' as example, id, title
,case 
   when regexp_like (title, 'Sales', 'i') then 'Sales'
   else q'[It's something else]'
 end as flag
from x;
```